# C#: Simplifying many similar implicit operator methods

Tags: c#, generics, refactoring, operators

I have a class with a bunch of `implicit operator`s. In the code below, only a few examples of the `implicit operator`s are used. I'm looking for any ideas how to refactor this, without making the `SafeValue` class generic. Any ideas?

```
public class SafeValue {
    private readonly object value;
    public SafeValue(object value) {
        if (value == somethingSpecial) {
            value = null;
        }
        this.value = value;
    }
    public static implicit operator string(SafeValue instance) {
        return (string)instance.value;
    }
    public static implicit operator int(SafeValue instance) {
        if (instance.value == null) {
            throw new InvalidCastException("Cannot convert type");
        }
        return (int)instance.value;
    }
    public static implicit operator int?(SafeValue instance) {
        if (instance.value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return new int?((int)instance.value);
    }
    public static implicit operator DateTime(SafeValue instance)
        if (instance.value == null) {
            throw new InvalidCastException("Cannot convert type");
        }
        return (DateTime)instance.value;
    }
    public static implicit operator DateTime?(SafeValue instance) {
        if (instance.value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return new DateTime?((DateTime)instance.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of this class?

Comment: Seems very dangerous...  Probably the worst named class ever, given what it can do.

Comment: As a comment, it is generally not a good idea to throw exceptions in an implicit operator.

Comment: Why do you not want to make the class generic? This type of scenario is *perfect* for genericization.

Comment: Implicit conversion is VERY tricky, you are basically going to torpedo a lot of type safety if you're not careful.  I'd either make them explicit (so you must at least cast) or provide a ToType<T>() generic method or something along those lines.

Comment: The purpose of this class is it's a wrapper to allow implicit conversion of a type that may have unacceptable values. Please just assume that we have to work within this framework. We're not trying to design the best class for the purpose; we're trying to refactor the existing code within the class. If you don't have a solution, no worries. Think of it as a challenge. :)

Comment: @Chris: how far are you willing to go on a refactor?  Must the implicit operators stay?  Is the point that the type inside MUST be the type you are converting to?  Or do you want acceptable conversions as well?

Comment: The best refactoring would probably be to trash that class. Not trying to be rude, but sometimes the best way to improve something is to remove it.

Comment: @UrbanEsc: on the whole i agree, if it were in my company's code I'd probably request a rewrite, but if he truly has constraints on keeping this interface to minimize changes...  sometimes our hands are tied by supervisors, managers, policies, etc...

Comment: @James Michael Hare I hate it when my supervisors tie my hands to a ticking time bomb doused in radioactive gasoline.

Comment: @James: Any refactor that does not change SafeValue to a generic, and 1) throws when trying to convert a null to an value type, as in `int i = new SafeValue(null)`; 2) Can convert value types and reference types, eg: `int i = new SafeValue(5)` and `string name = new SafeValue("chris")`;

Comment: As i said in my answer you dont need the null check + manually raised exception. If its null, there will be an exception when you try to cast anyway. So what is the point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As i said in the comments, i think it would be best to replace the code completely.

If that is not an option, you might consider the following, mostly cosmetic changes:

- You might want to get rid of the manually thrown exceptions. Why check for null and throw an exception if you would do so anyway in the next line? You are throwing exceptions in there anyway. Casting null to int **will** result in an exception.
- Why all the *new* s ? No need for them. Just cast.
- No need to doublecast your *Nullables*.

  ```
  DateTime? dt = (DateTime?) DateTime.Now;
  ```

Works as expected

```
    DateTime? dt = (DateTime?) null;
```

Also works (that is what you are doing anyway, since you *return null;* in your function that has a return value of *DateTime?* in the signature, right?

All your functions get reduced to only one line of code. Here is the *DateTime?* one in all its glory:

```
public static implicit operator DateTime?(SafeValue instance) {    
    return (DateTime?)instance.value;    
}
```

Repeat for *int?* and the like.